# when should each of two different formulas be used to calculate the area of an asymmetric lens?

Tags: geometry

While watching one of Presh Talwalkar's videos he derives the general formula for the area of an asymmetric lens (notated as the intersection of a circle with radius $a$ and a circle with radius $b$) to be:

$$(a^2 - b^2)\arctan\biggl(\frac{b}{a}\biggr) + \frac{\pi b^2}{2} - ab$$

He derives this formula due to the fact that in his example the kite that connects the two circles' center points and intersection points is a right kite.

[image]

Wolfram Alpha, however, has a different and much more complicated general formula which involves a third parameter $d$, the distance between the circles' center points: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html

How can I know when I can use each formula?  In what cases is the connecting kite guaranteed to be a right kite?  If I were to give this as a homework problem, would I be restricted to using certain radius lengths in the latter case?

Comment: Please include the MathWorld result in the body of the question to make it self-contained. Readers shouldn't have to click-through to a separate site to understand what you're asking. ... Good luck!

Comment: In your image, the two semicircles intersect at right angles, or equivalently at the intersections the tangent to one semicircle is the radius of the other circle. Is that given?

Comment: Blue - that particular page is way too detailed and complicated to write out.

Answer (score 1):

The first formula works when the kite is a right kite. To determine if it is a right kite, you could check whether the distance between the two centers is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

For the latter formula from Wolfram alpha,

1, The first two parts of the formula has the restriction that d, r, and R should be able to form a triangle.

2, The third part has the restriction that the radicand has to be positive.

From here, can you show that 1 and 2 is equivalent and express the restriction algebraically?

Comment: Thanks.  What if I don't know the distance between the two centers?  (i.e. it's not given and it's not on a grid with coordinates)

Comment: @Nate As long as there is an asymmetric lens, meaning that the two circles intersect, you could use the Wolfram alpha formula.